# Windows 7 Logo Certification Test for program that requires reboot during installation

Tags: windows-7, logo-testing

I am using Windows Software Logo Kit for win7 logo certification testing. But it seems you cannot save your session during the test. Right now I have a program that requires reboot during installation and it couldn't get uninstalled to finish the test if I cancel the reboot.

Does anyone have the same issue before?

Many thanks!

Cheers,
Zhe

Answer (score 1):

OK. It won't pass the certification test. Here is the reason:

http://connect.microsoft.com/site831/content/content.aspx?ContentID=16647